# Problema para compilar libreria boost en QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy intentando usar esta libreria en un proyecto en QT pero nunca la reconoce.
Basicamente pongo estas librerias:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
```

Codigo de mi proyecto:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += C++11

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11

TARGET = intento
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    scheduler.cpp

HEADERS += \
    scheduler.h \
    standard_miner.hpp
```

Lo que hago es lo siguiente bajarme la libreria precompilada boost:
http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-boost-past/

¿Pero ahora tengo que incluirlo en mi proyecto o que debo hacer???

Referencia del programa:
https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcoin_miningsim

Y obviamente no las reconoce. Entonces lo que tengo es que bajarmelas y digamos incluirselas a mi programa pienso ya que no se me ocurre otra manera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿A que te refieres con que no las reconoce? ¿El compilador se queja de que no encuentra el archivo, el *linker* se queja de que no encuentra la librería?, ¿Cuál es el mensaje exacto?

¿Están las librerías Boost correctamente instaladas?

¿Es necesario indicarle a qmake donde buscar las cabeceras?
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

¿Le indicas a qmake las librerías externas a utilizar?
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

**EDITO**

qmake tiene opciones para indicar tanto las rutas a los archivos de cabecera como las librerías a enlazar.

**INCLUDEPATH**: rutas en las que buscar los archivos de cabecera. Al igual que cualquier otra variable de qmake, se puede *asignar* (olvidando el valor anterior) mediante `INCLUDEPATH=`, o bien se le pueden *añadir* contenidos, colocandolos a continuación de los previos (si los tuviera) mediante `INCLUDEPATH+=`

> INCLUDEPATH
>
> Specifies the #include directories which should be searched when
>   compiling the project.
>
> For example:
>
> INCLUDEPATH = c:/msdev/include d:/stl/include To specify a path
>   containing spaces, quote the path using the technique described in
>   Whitespace.
>
> win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:/mylibs/extra headers" unix:INCLUDEPATH +=
>   "/home/user/extra headers"

**LIBS**: librerías a enlazar. Como variable que es, se le puede *asignar* un valor con `LIBS=` o *añadir* al anterior mediante `LIBS+=`.

> LIBS
>
> Specifies a list of libraries to be linked into the project. If you
>   use the Unix -l (library) and -L (library path) flags, qmake handles
>   the libraries correctly on Windows (that is, passes the full path of
>   the library to the linker). The library must exist for qmake to find
>   the directory where a -l lib is located.
>
> For example:
>
> unix:LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lmath win32:LIBS += c:/mylibs/math.lib
>   To specify a path containing spaces, quote the path using the
>   technique described in Whitespace.
>
> win32:LIBS += "C:/mylibs/extra libs/extra.lib" unix:LIBS +=
>   "-L/home/user/extra libs" -lextra

Comment: Voy re-formular la pregunta con lo que estoy intentando.

Comment: Las preguntas al autor del hilo deberían añadirse como comentarios. Por otro lado poner una respuesta únicamente con enlaces es contraproducente porque esos enlaces pueden dejar de ser válidos en el futuro... lo que hará que tu respuesta sea totalmente estéril. Te recomiendo editar la respuesta para adaptarla a la política del portal: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer